# Create a custom Hook for splitting strings (React JS)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm working with React JS (hooks) for recently. For a project, I need to split many strings in different divs. So, I created a function to this, that saves me some time! My actual question is : Should I create a custom Hook instead of my function ? 

 Of course, the actual code works, but as a beginner, I don't know if my way is clean. I need feedbacks cause my main goal to write the best and clear code as possible.

```
// Splitting Texts
const splitText = str => {
  return (
    <div>
      {str.split(' ').map((item, index) => {
        return (
          <div key={index}>
            {item}
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

// Main App
export default function App() {
  const name = splitText('Lucie Bachman');
  const description = splitText('Hey, this is my first post on StackOverflow!');

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>{name}</h1> 
      <h2>{description}</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Expected results :

```
<h1>
  <div>
    <div>Lucie</div>
    <div>Bachman</div>
  </div>
</h1>
```

I'm super excited to have joined the community!
Thanks to you, and take care.

Lucie Bachman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A custom hook is something `that uses out of the box react hooks` to actually provide a logic and return data.

If the function returns JSX, its actually just a function or can be used as a functional component

Since you only want to split string once you can convert it into  a component and use `React.memo` to optimize rendering

```
// Splitting Texts
const SplitText = React.memo(({str}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {str.split(' ').map((item, index) => {
        return (
          <div key={index}>
            {item}
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
});

// Main App
export default function App() {

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1><SplitText str={'Lucie Bachman'} /></h1> 
      <h2><SplitText str={'Hey, this is my first post on StackOverflow!''} /></h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks Shubham Khatri!